# Locking specific cells in excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro I am working on currently.

**Purpose**
The objective in that once there is a value in column L , i need cells in the revelant row to lock. However this should not lock the whole worksheet, just the cells.

**Code**
Below is the code i have been been playing with. I am trying amend the code so to achieve my purpose above.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row = 1 Then
        If Target.Column = 3 Or Target.Column = 5 Then
            Beep
            Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Offset(0, 1).Select
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

**Example**
[image]

The cells which will be locked are in **yellow**, if there is a date in **column L**

The reason why locking the whole worksheet wont overcome the problem is because any additional users will not be able to input there own data into the worksheet.

Answer (score 2):

Merely locking the cells has no effect unless you protect the sheet. Firstly, unlock all the cells in the sheet, and then try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column <> 12 Or Target.Row = 1 Then Exit Sub

    Range(Cells(Target.Row, 2), Cells(Target.Row, 11)).Locked = True
    ActiveSheet.Protect
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but this locks the worksheet . Meaning no other data can be entered into the excel worksheet.

Comment: @James, did you unlock all the cells of the worksheet before running this?

Answer (score 0):

Change the password in the first line of code with the actual password to unprotect the sheet.

```
Const PW As String = "123"

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
Dim r As Long
If Target.Column = 12 And Target.Row > 1 Then
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=PW
    r = Target.Row
    If Target <> "" Then
        Range("B" & r & ":K" & r).Locked = True
    Else
        Range("B" & r & ":K" & r).Locked = False
    End If
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=PW
End If
End Sub
```